# using find command to filter file names with no control character in RHEL 4

Tags: regex, emacs, find, filenames

I'm trying to use the "find" command to select file names with no weird character (as CR, LN, DEL,...).

The following command lines work fine in **RHEL 5**:

```
find /dir -type f -regextype egrep -regex '^[[:print:]]+$'
find /dir -type f -regextype egrep -regex '^[^[:cntrl:]]+$'
```

But it doesn't in **RHEL 4**, because the regextype option is not available in version 4.1.20 of find command.

According to a doc (*/usr/share/info/find.info.gz*) in findutils package:

```
*Note Syntax of Regular Expressions: (emacs)Regexps, for a
*description of the syntax of regular expressions.
```

And I am very confused trying to understand the Emacs Regular Expressions because in a subdirectory where the only file is

```
aaaa
```

the following command lines do work:

```
find . -type f -regex '\./[:alnum:]+'
find . -type f -regex '\./[:alpha:]+'
```

but these other ones do not:

```
find . -type f -regex '\./[:print:]+'
find . -type f -regex '\./[^[:cntrl:]]+'
```

Why some character classes are accepted and not others?
Do you know other way to get that in RHEL 4?

Thanx in advance

Comment: That later syntax isn't specifying the alphanumeric character class, it specifies to match any characters which literally match a, l, n, u, m or colon. Emacs has number of ways to specify characters, but I don't know what they mean in that info file you quote. Also, depending on what exactly do you want to filter out, maybe `\s_` (symbol constituent) or `\ca` (ASCII character) would do.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[\x20-\x7E]` instead of `[:print:]` and `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]` instead of `[:cntrl:]`.

Comment: I'm sorry but your suggestion does not work :(... because of the hexadecimal codes :)...  Just replace the hexadecimal codes by the right ASCII chars, then it works!    **`find . -type f -regex '[ -~]+'
./aaaa`**

Comment: Well, I guess that's one way to do it :)

Comment: @Jdamian Emacs has several other ways of specifying non-printable characters, for instance, octal `"\000"` is the null character, or `"\C-j"` end-of-line character. Perhaps you could try some of those (not sure how'd you replace "\x00" with ASCII char...